# How right scale canvas? (html)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've prepared [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/tender-fog-dvxuez?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for my case (just change something into js file for render map).
In short, I have source of map (coordinates, and sprites), and i need to draw this map.
I have following algorithm:

```
for(let x in data.region.draw_info){
            const cellX = data.region.draw_info[x];
            for(let y in cellX){
                const cellY = cellX[y];
                for(let cell of cellY){
                    ctx.drawImage(image, constans[cell[0]].x*1, constans[cell[0]].y*1, 32, 32, x*32, y*32, 32,32);
                }
            }
        }
```

As you see, I use:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, constans[cell[0]].x, constans[cell[0]].y, 32, 32, x*32, y*32, 32,32);
```

Where: *drawImage(image, **space_source_x**, **space_source_y**, **size_cut_source_x**, **size_cut_source_y**, **space_canvas_x**, **space_canvas_y**, **size_put_canvas_x**, **size_put_canvas_y**)*

I guess, I filled right function drawImage, but I got cut of map (I have map 70x70, but I got render 9x5):

[image]

If I scale canvas, I will get full map, than my algorithm is right, but I think I have mistake in using **drawImage**

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your line with the following, it draws all the images (but at a tiny scale)

```
ctx.drawImage(image, constans[cell[0]].x, constans[cell[0]].y, 2.2, 2.2, x*2.2, y*2.2, 2.2,2.2);
```

Comment: You are totally right. I did something like that with  ctx.scale, but I just need to render my map with right scale 1:1